# Is there an Integrated Security=SSPI option for Send-MailMessage?

Tags: powershell

I have a table storing email variables/values that are called through powershell queries in my script.

```
Send-MailMessage -From $From_Email -To $To_Email -Subject $Job_Success_Email_Subject -Body $Email_Body -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -port $SmtpPort -Credential $SmtpCredentials -usessl
```

I am mainly interested in the Username/Password credentials being passed from DB, but i have been getting this error when using `Get-Credential`:

```
$SmtpCredentials = Get-Credential
```

> Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server
>   response was: Authentication required

if i pass in my credentials from DB like this instead:

```
$SmtpPassword = $SmtpPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$SmtpCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($SmtpUser,$SmtpPassword)
```

Note: the password is NOT encrypted for now just for testing purposes!

i get these 2 errors:

> New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the
>   argument count: "2".

and then i get a Credential popup login, and if i enter nothing, i get this error:

> Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Credential'.
>   The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or
>   empty, and then try the command again.

if I do enter the credentials manually, i get this instead:

> Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the
>   client was not authenticated. The server response was: Authentication
>   required

I know this error has threads discussed and answered, but I have gone through all possible solutions, such as `usessl` and the `ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force` but its not working. I have also tried `[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$SmtpPassword` but that seems to have no effect either.

So for now, in order to ensure that its not an issue with the credentials itself, i would like to test with something like `Integrated Security=SSPI` like sql connection string allows but for the Send-Mail command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem!

so apparently the ID (Username) i was using was not in the Active Directory group. so i used another ID that was in the AD group and it worked!

for example:

i am scripting in Dev environment and thought I just need to use the Dev ID and password, which didnt work no matter what i tried.

I tried the Test environment ID/password which was recently built/requested to be added in AD group in the script im writing in Dev, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `System.Net.NetworkCredential` object to pass credentials. Between try this. it works flawlessly everytime.

```
Function Send-Email {
    Param (
        [Parameter(`
            Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$SendTo,
        [Parameter(`
            Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Subject,
        [Parameter(`
            Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Body,
        [Parameter(`
            Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$EmailFrom="abc@123.com",  #This gives a default value to the $EmailFrom command
        [Parameter(`
            mandatory=$false)]
        [String]$attachment,
        [Parameter(`
            mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Password
    )

        $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
        $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$SendTo,$Subject,$Body)
        if ($attachment -ne $null) {
            $SMTPattachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)
            $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($SMTPattachment)
        }
        $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
        $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
        $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($EmailFrom.Split("@")[0], $Password); 
        $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
        Remove-Variable -Name SMTPClient
        Remove-Variable -Name Password

}
```

Invoke using

```
Send-EMail -SendTo "him@hotmail.com" -Body "Test Body" -Subject "Test Subject" -attachment "C:\something.pdf" -password "Password"
```

Comment: I have tried a similar version of that example prior to this, and i still received error. regardless, i still recieved an error trying your code: Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required"

Comment: ok so idk what happened but now the script is running fine, however, i am getting no email whatsoever

Comment: Also, where us the field for username? How can it accept password without knowing username?

Comment: Email from is the username

Comment: Wait really? Then what about the email from who it really is sending from? What if I am not sending from the the same email everytime ...